# Why does QuickTime not play a video with CRF of 0, but is happy with 10?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, quicktime

I'm experimenting with video compression using `ffmpeg` (version 4.2.2), and used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset fast newCrf0.mp4
```

but the resulting video would not play on QuickTime Version 10.5, on MacOS 10.14. The rather unhelpful error message was : "*The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.*"

After failing to find an explanation, I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -preset fast newCrf10.mp4
```

and QuickTime played it.
I am very curious to find out what's going on.

Here are the summaries from `ffprobe` for each file:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner newCrf0.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'newCrf0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:34.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4114 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 3979 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler


$ ffprobe -hide_banner newCrf10.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'newCrf10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:34.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1146 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1010 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Clearly, there's a difference in the video streams:
`h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive)` vs `h264 (High)`.

- What does that mean?
- Is that the root of the problem?
- Is CRF=0 problematic with other players?

Ref: [FFmpeg H.264 video encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Answer (score 2):

QuickTime only supports H.264 with YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling, but using `-crf 0` results in 4:4:4.

Any FFmpeg based player such as VLC or mpv will support these files.

Comment: Thank you @llogan. That's interesting. The ffprobe output for the file generated using `-crf 0` includes `yuv420p`. Im assuming that doesn't contradict it also saying `h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive)`. But why not? I'm new to this and keen to understand what's going on.